# Multiple Histogram in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data frame obtained from the titanic dataset which looks like this

```
pd.crosstab(full[0:890]['Fsize'], full[0:890]['Survived'])

Survived    0.0 1.0
Fsize       
1          373  163
2          72   89
3          43   59
4          8    21
5          12   3
6          19   3
7          8    4
8          6    0
11         7    0
```

Now I want a plot which looks like this in R

[image]

However I want to get this using matplotlib. For this the code I am using is

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = pd.crosstab(full[0:890]['Fsize'], full[0:890]['Survived']).as_matrix()
colors = ['No','Yes']
ax.hist(full[0:890]['Fsize'], histtype='bar', color=colors, label= 'Survived')
ax.legend(prop={'size': 10})
ax.set_title('bars with legend')
plt.show()
```

which gives me an error

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "No"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "No"
could not convert string to float: 'no'
```

I am new to matplotlib so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The code I could figure out is

```
fsize_survive_cross = pd.crosstab(full[0:890]['Fsize'], full[0:890]['Survived'])
fsize_survive_cross.plot(kind='bar',title='Survival Rate by Family Size')
```

Yielding plot

[image]